# Does a stochastic integral depend on the index of the variable of the integration?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Is true that $\int_0^t f(u)dW_u$ is just $f(t)W_t$ where $W_u$ is Wiener process?
I know that $\int_0^t const \text{ }dW_u = const \cdot W_t$ but this is not the case as $f$ depends on the variable of the integration.

Comment: No, it's not true (unless $f$ is constant). Consider e.g. $f(u)=1_{[0,1]}(u)$, then $\int_0^t f(u) \, dW_u = W_1 \neq 0 = W_t f(t)$ for $t>1$.

Comment: It makes sense, thx. If the function is determined continuously (and takes only one value for every $t$) like $e^{au}$ is this the case?

Comment: No, it doesn't... it really just works if $f$ is constant. (Do you know Itô's formula? If so, then it should be clear that this can only hold for $f$ constant.)